# Pre-release and build-metadata in semver version of universal package supported?

Tags: azure-artifacts

we want to use universal packages to store certain artifacts that our azure pipelines yaml build is producing. From the doc of universal packages I can see that semver is supported.
I am now asking what the exact string pattern for version of universal packages look like and if pre-release and build-metadata label (that is defined in semver) are supported too for universal packages.

Concretely would following versions be supported: 1.0.0-alpha+gitsha1 or 1.0.0+gitsha1 or 2.1.2-beta

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described clearly in our official doc here-- [Publish a Universal Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops#publish-a-universal-package)

> Update these values as desired, and use the feed name that you noted
>   earlier. Package names must be lowercase and can use only letters,
>   numbers, and dashes (-).*emphasized text*
>
> Package versions must be lowercase [Semantic Versioning (SemVer)
>   2.0.0](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html) **without build metadata (+ suffix)**.

So only 2.1.2-beta is supported in your given sample.

Comment: So the pre-release has to be _lower-case_?